# How to get total count of records in flat file in ssis

Tags: ssis

i need to create a job which has varying number of columns (datatype also changes) as flat file source and load data into falt file destination. I need to get the Row count of the records in the last row of the flat file destination.

Note: today i receive input file with 25 columns i need to get the row count as 25, tomorrow i receive with 50 cloumns where i need to get the row count as 50.

How to create a flat file source which has varying number of columns every time.

Comment: Is it fixed width columns or delimited and what is the row delimiter? Are there any header rows and footer rows? A sample will help.

Comment: it is csv delimiter, it has no header rows. Only one footer, that footer has to display the Row count.

Comment: Can you paste a sample of your source flat file as well.